Compute $\int_{|z|=1} |z^5-1|^2 \hspace{0.1cm} |dz|$
Compute $$\int_{|z|=1} |z^5-1|^2 \hspace{0.1cm} |dz|$$
Let $z = e^{i \theta}$. Then $dz  = iz \hspace{0.1cm} d\theta$ gives $|dz| = |z| |d \theta| =  |e^{i \theta}| |d \theta|$
Then
\begin{align}
    |z^5-1| &= |e^{i 5 \theta} -1| = |\cos 5 \theta + i \sin 5 \theta -1| = \sqrt{(\cos 5 \theta -1)^2 + (\sin 5 \theta)^2} \\
    &= \sqrt{\cos^2 5 \theta - 2 \cos 5 \theta +1 + \sin^2 5 \theta}  = \sqrt{2 -2 \cos 5 \theta} 
\end{align}
Squaring both sides, it follows that $|z^5-1|^2 =  |2-2 \cos 5 \theta| = 2-2 \cos 5 \theta$ since $2-2 \cos 5 \theta \geq 0$ for all $\theta$. Then
\begin{align}
    \int_{|z|=1} |z^5-1|^2 \hspace{0.1cm} |dz| &=  \int_0^{2\pi} (2 -2 \cos 5 \theta) |e^{i \theta}| |d \theta| \\
    &= \int_0^{2 \pi} (2-2 \cos 5 \theta) |d \theta| \\
    &= \left[2 \theta  -2 \cdot \frac{\sin 5\theta}{5}\right]_0^{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi \\
    &= 2\pi\left[4\pi - 2 \cdot \frac{\sin 10 \pi}{5} \right] - 2\pi\left[ 0 - 2 \cdot \frac{\sin 0}{5} \right] \\
    &= 8\pi 
    \end{align}
Did I make any serious blunders? I'm particularly shaky on understanding how to use $|dz|$ properly in complex integration.

You don't want that $2\pi$ factor, but after using it you drop a $\pi$ anyway.

@J.G. what happens to the $|d \theta|$ then? On one hand, I'm tempted to integrate directly, but when $\int$ is taken with respect to $| \cdot|$, usually all the work boils down to taking the modulus of everything, including the initial integrant

Your integral is just $\int_0^{2\pi}(2-2\cos5\theta)d\theta$.

You made several mistakes in the latter part of your workings.
$$\begin{align}
    \int_{|z|=1} |z^5-1|^2 \hspace{0.1cm} |dz| &=  \int_0^{2\pi} (2 -2 \cos 5 \theta) |e^{i \theta}| d \theta.
\end{align}$$
The quantity $d\theta$ is real and positive, you can drop the absolute value symbol around it.
$$\begin{align}
    &= \int_0^{2 \pi} (2-2 \cos 5 \theta) d \theta \\
    &= \left[2 \theta  -2 \cdot \frac{\sin 5x}{5}\right]_0^{2\pi}.
\end{align}$$
There is no factor of $2\pi$ in the antiderivative.
$$\begin{align}
    &= \left[4\pi - 2 \cdot \frac{\sin 10 \pi}{5} \right] - \left[ 0 - 2 \cdot \frac{\sin 0}{5} \right] \\
    &= 4\pi .
    \end{align}$$
Here $5\theta=10\pi\not=20\pi$ in your function evaluation, and with correct rendering of the factors we see that the result is $4\pi$, not $8\pi$.

We can convert this integral to a meromorphic form that can be evaluated using the Residue Theorem. First render
$|z^5-1|^2=(z^5-1)(\overline{z}^5-1)=(z^5-1)(z^{-5}-1),\tag{1}$
where we use the fact that along the circle where you're integrating, $\overline{z}=1/z=z^{-1}$.
Next we observe that the rotation from $dz$ on the counterclockwise unit circle to $|dz|$, which is directed parallel to the positive real axis, is $-(\theta+\pi/2)$ where $\theta$ is the argument of $z$. So
$|dz|=(|z|/iz)dz=-i\hspace{0.1 cm} dz/z,\tag{2}$
where again we render $|z|=1$ along the integration path.
From (1) and (2) we then have
$$\begin{align}
    \int_{|z|=1} |z^5-1|^2 \hspace{0.1cm} |dz|
&=\int_{|z|=1}(-z^5+2-z^{-5})(-iz^{-1}\hspace{0.1 cm}dz)\\
&=\int_{|z|=1}(iz^4-2iz^{-1}+iz^{-6})dz.
\end{align}$$
It becomes evident that only the second term contributes to the residue of the pole at $z=0$, so this residue is $-2i$. Multiplying by $2\pi i$ in accordance with the Residue Theorem then gives $4\pi$ in agreement with the corrected development above.

OK, the reason for the downvote has to be good. The question shows workings, the math is correct as far as I know, so — ¿qué pasa?

I didn't downvote the question, but I must wonder: why do we not have $|dz| = 2\pi \cdot 1 = 2 \pi$, i.e. the appropriate arc length? Perhaps you're familiar with my confusion? Maybe I am confusing two different things. Can you help me distinguish the difference between my understanding and yours?

It is true that $\int|dz|$ around the circle is $2\pi$. But you are not integrating $|dz|$ directly, so there is no direct factor of $2\pi$.

I did not downvote your answer but upvoted it in support of your answer.

Thanks Clayton, I wanted to know what was wrong according to the fownviter -> opportunity to improve.
